# class variable alternates values in while loop, but only when in a routed function

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to python so please take it easy on me. I'm sure that there are better ways to do what I am trying to achieve. It's a learning process.

I have a class in which I define a variable and then alter it's setting later in the code (I want it to do something based on the condition of the variable and run all the time in the background).

When I do this in a function, it works as expected. However, when I do this in a routed function for Flask the variable oscillates between how it was set when the thread was launched and what it gets changed to by the routed function. It does this each time through the loop.

I don't understand why it does it, but I haven't been able to fix it and was looking for some assistance. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#import time for time functionality
import time

##import flask 
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response, json
app = Flask(__name__)


#import threading to run processes in background as threads
import threading

class param:
        status = {
                'VariableToWatch' : 'Condition-1' 
        }

class myThread (threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self, threadID, name):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.threadID = threadID
                self.name = name
                self.signal = True


        def run(self):
                while self.signal:
                        print 'In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is', param.status['VariableToWatch']
                        if param.status['VariableToWatch'] == 'Run':
                                print 'VariableToWatch is', param.status['VariableToWatch']

                        if param.status['VariableToWatch'] != 'Run':
                                print 'VariableToWatch is', param.status['VariableToWatch']

                        time.sleep(1)



# main web page    
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

        print 'At the index function'
        param.status['VariableToWatch'] = 'Condition-2'
        raw_input('Waiting..... Press ENTER to continue')



if __name__ == "__main__":

        #Launch the heating thread
        ThreadID_7 = myThread(7, "HeatMe")
        ThreadID_7.start()

        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
        server = WSGIServer(("", 5000), app)
        server.serve_forever()
```

and the output looks like this prior to hitting it with a browser:

```
In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is Condition-1
VariableToWatch is Condition-1
In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is Condition-1
VariableToWatch is Condition-1
In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is Condition-1
VariableToWatch is Condition-1
```

After you hit it with a browser and the routed function is called:

```
VariableToWatch is Condition-1
In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is Condition-2
VariableToWatch is Condition-2
In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is Condition-1
VariableToWatch is Condition-1
In the myThread Loop. VariableToWatch is Condition-2
VariableToWatch is Condition-2
```

Answer (score 3):

WSGI may run your program multiple times, creating multiple running instances to serve requests.  On each of these runs, the class called `param` is created.  So you probably actually have multiple classes called `param`, each in its own process.  You can check on this by doing `print(id(param))` in the same place where you print your little status check; you will probably see different values printed.

You can't safely store anything in global state when using something like WSGI.  You'll need to use a database, or session-management tools for Flask, or some other network-aware solution to persist data across multiple requests.  How to do it depends on how persistent you want it to be (i.e., do you want it to last for a single user's session, or a single view of a single page, or what).

Comment: OK - I think I understand why it's doing what it's doing, but that doesn't necessarily offer me a solution. Is there any way to alter a variable running in a threaded function from WSGI / the application?

Comment: @apriliarider: I mentioned a few possible solutions in my answer: database, session-management, etc.  The bottom line is that when it comes to programs that are serving web content, you can't rely on global program state *at all* (whether it's threaded or not), because you may have many requests coming in in an unpredictable order.  It's hard to make a more specific recommendation without knowing exactly what it is you're trying to do, but my hunch is that rather than "find a way to do this", you'll probably need to radically rethink what you're doing.